# Filter Django-Function-View Queryset for User.Request

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**Models.py**

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_held = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    year_from = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    year_to = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    info = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('resume')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.company_name
```

**Views.py**

```
def Resume(request):
    experience = Experience.objects.filter(user = request.user)

    return render(request, 'resume.html', {'experience': experience})
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
    {% for an_experience in experience %}
    <a href="{% url 'edit_experience' an_experience.pk %}"><li ><h5>{{ an_experience }},</h5></a> {{ an_experience.company_address }} - {{ an_experience.post_held }}</li>
    <small>{{ an_experience.year_from }} - {{ an_experience.year_to }}</small>
    <div>
        {{ an_experience.info }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

if I use `.all()`, it is working perfectly but while trying to filter it using `request.user` nothing is displaying in the template file.

Comment: What is `request.user`? Is it the user object that you expect? What is the value of `experience` in `Resume()`? Does it have the value you expect? You should start by debugging your code, either with `print()` statements or with a debugger.

Comment: As you can see, using `.all()` work means that  `.filter(user=request.user)` return **0 results**. No matching query is found. Begin by ensure that all the Experiences objects have their user attribute set (_because you set null=true in the Experience model_). And also try to filter like this : `.filter(user_id=request.user.id)`

Comment: did you logged in . please check whether the user is logged in or not otherwise request.user will provide null value.

Comment: Yes I logged in